# sql server select min value from matching datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Id, Value, Sender, Recipient, MIN(DateTime), TypeOf, VideoId, Likes, Comments
FROM xx.dbo.StreamView
WHERE StreamView.TypeOf = 3 AND StreamView.[DateTime] >= "Some DateTime Value Here"
```

I am trying to get the latest record directly newer than the given `DateTime` value.

when executing this query I am receiving the following error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Some DateTime Value Here'.
```

Also, when removing this line `AND StreamView.[DateTime] >= "Some DateTime Value Here"`

I am getting:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'xx.dbo.StreamView.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Suggestions? Thanks.

### Update

```
WITH
  sequenced_records AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    xx.dbo.StreamView
  WHERE
    StreamView.TypeOf = 3
    AND StreamView.[DateTime] >= "2011-12-29 01:38:21.607"
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_records
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

returns -> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name '2011-12-29 01:38:21.607'.

### Update 2

guys I need to return just a SINGLE record with the minimum datetime in a group of selected items bigger than the given datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIN() is an aggregate, and as the error says; you must use GROUP BY to use aggregate queries.  This means that you can't get the MIN() of a group *and* have the individual values from one record in the group at the same time.

There are two alternatives...
- Use GROUP BY to get the MIN() and then use that to look up the record it matches.
- Use an alternative approach, such as ROW_NUMBER()

```
WITH
  sequenced_records AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DateTime] ASC) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    xx.dbo.StreamView
  WHERE
    StreamView.TypeOf = 3
    AND StreamView.[DateTime] >= "Some DateTime Value Here"
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_records
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

***NOTE*** You do need real datetime in there, such as '01012012 23:34'

For environments without ROW_NUMBER() you'd revert to the aggregate approach, using two steps.  Such as...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  StreamView
WHEREE
  TypeOf = 3
  AND DateTime = (SELECT MIN(DateTime) FROM StreamView WHERE TypeOf = 3 AND DateTime >= '01012012 23:34')
```

Comment: @user1027620 - You're using the wrong quotes around the date.  Use `'`.

Comment: @user1027620 - Also, I should have had ASC, not DESC.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Dems your solution works perfectly, I would just like to ask how about if nothing returns using the given date, instead the query would return the first item it finds going backwards from that date?

Comment: @user1027620 - As a *single* query it's messy and inefficient.  So add something like `IF (@@row_count = 0) <NewQuery>` to find the preceding record if and only if no superceding record is found.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use an aggregate function like `MIN()`, you must group the non-aggregate columns using a `GROUP BY` clause.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

You also need to replace the double quotes in `"Some DateTime Value Here"` with single quotes.

**Try this code:**

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    Value, 
    Sender, 
    Recipient, 
    MIN([DateTime]), 
    TypeOf, 
    VideoId, 
    Likes, 
    Comments
FROM xx.dbo.StreamView

WHERE StreamView.TypeOf = 3 AND StreamView.[DateTime] >= '1/1/2012'

GROUP BY
    Id, 
    Value, 
    Sender, 
    Recipient, 
    TypeOf, 
    VideoId, 
    Likes, 
    Comments
```

Per the updated question:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = (
    SELECT MIN( [DateTime] ) FROM xx.dbo.StreamView WHERE TypeOf = 3 
        AND [DateTime] >= '1/1/2012' 
);

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM xx.dbo.StreamView WHERE [DateTime] >= @Date;
```

Comment: why? should i group everything else? what if the table had a billion columns.

Comment: + the invalid column thing is still giving me the same error. :/

Comment: If the table had a "billion columns", the database would need to know the aggregate behavior for every one of them. How else can it group them properly so that you can determine a minimum value of one column?

Comment: -1 : This answer is not functionally what the OP described.  It does remove an error, but it does not give the required functional behaviour (The first record after a specified date).

Comment: @Dems - to me, the question wasn't clear if the OP wanted a single record after a date for each Id/Sender/Recipient combo or a single record across the entire dataset. If a single record across the entire dataset was desired, then you are correct.

Comment: How about if nothing returns using a given date for the query to return the first item it finds going backwards from that date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub query instead:

```
SELECT Id, Value, Sender, Recipient, DateTime, TypeOf, VideoId, Likes, Comments
FROM xx.dbo.StreamView
WHERE StreamView.TypeOf = 3 
AND StreamView.[DateTime] = (Select MIN(DateTime) from xx.dbo.StreamView where [DateTime] >= 
'Some DateTime Value Here' AND TypeOf = 3)
```

Comment: You *must* specify the `TypeOf = 3` in both the main query and the sub query.  Else `MIN(DateTime)` may return a value for a record with a different value of `TypeOf`

Comment: guys I need to return just a SINGLE record with the minimum datetime in a group of selected items bigger than the given datetime.

Comment: @user1027620 - This will only return multiple records if multiple records are tied as being "next".  It's the same as the second query in my answer, and should work fine.